# paypal order total with laravel

Tags: laravel, api, paypal

Anybody using the PayPal API from srmklive with there laravel project?

https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal

Have installed it and I have made it work, till I got the following error.
I have been searching for hours, but can't find the solution.

What would be the problem here?
It keeps saying the following; Order total is invalid.

```
Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2018-06-27T08:06:32Z [CORRELATIONID] => c8e16efc9b6e4 [ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 123 [BUILD] => 47483429 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10401 [L_ERRORCODE1] => 10426 [L_ERRORCODE2] => 10431 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details. [L_SHORTMESSAGE1] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details. [L_SHORTMESSAGE2] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details. [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Order total is invalid. [L_LONGMESSAGE1] => Item total is invalid. [L_LONGMESSAGE2] => Item amount is invalid. [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error [L_SEVERITYCODE1] => Error [L_SEVERITYCODE2] => Error [paypal_link] => )
```

I don't see anything about the order total in the documentation?
Or am I missing something?

The code I am using right now;

```
`$provider = new ExpressCheckout;

        $data = [];
        $order_id = 1;

        $data['items'] = [
            [
                'name'  => 'Product 1',
                'price' => 9.99,
                'qty'   => 1,
            ],
        ];
        $data['return_url'] = url('/paypal/ec-checkout-success');

        $data['invoice_id'] = config('paypal.invoice_prefix').'_'.$order_id;
        $data['invoice_description'] = "Order #$order_id Invoice";
        $data['cancel_url'] = url('/');
        $total = 0;

        foreach ($data['items'] as $item) {
            $total += $item['price'] * $item['qty'];
        }

        $data['total'] = $total;

        //return print_r($data);

        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data);

        //return dd($respons);

        // This will redirect user to PayPal
        return print_r($response); `
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the above problem.
Somehow PayPal doesn't accept the 9.99 USD
When I make a round number like 10 USD it works.